# Second derivative test of a function of two variables

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative

From the following relation:
[image]

How can we conclude the following rules:

(i) Minima if both $f_{xx}$ and $f_{yy}$ are positive and $(f_{xy})^2 < f_{xx} f_{yy}$,

(ii) Maxima if both $f_{xx}$ and $f_{yy}$  are negative and $(f_{xy})^2 < f_{xx}f_{yy}$,

(iii) Saddle points if $f_{xx}$ and $f_{yy}$  have opposite signs or $(f_{xy})^2 > f_{xx}f_{yy}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hints: (i) In this case the terms on the right are all positive.
       (ii) Similar to (i) but with different sign.
       (iii) If $f_{xx}$ is positive then if change in $y$ is $0$ then the difference on the left is positive. But if change in $x$ is $0$ then the difference on the left is negative. If $f_{xx}$ is negative apply a similar analysis of the problem to conclude there is a saddle. If $f_{xy}^{2}>f_{xx}f_{yy}$ but $f_{xx}$ and $f_{yy}$ have the same sign then a similar analysis on changes in $x$ and $y$ reveals a saddle. The cases may coindcide so paying close attention to sign and make one of the differences $\Delta x$ and $\Delta y$ equal to $0$ reveals a saddle again.

Comment: point (i) is ok. Regarding point (ii), how is similar to (i)? I think to ascertain that the equation gives a negative value, we would choose $(f_{xy})^{2} >f_{xx}f_{yy}$
Regarding (iii), I really can't understand it, could you illustrate it?

Comment: I just meant that the analysis is roughly the same for the second question. Given the information you want to show that the left side is less than $0$. Also notice that you have to divide by $f_{xx}$ to get the identity on the right. This means the inequality changes from "<" to ">". For (iii) we wish to conclude that that there is a saddle at $(x_{0},y_{0})$. This means we need one direction where the approximation is positive and one where it is negative.